# leecode21, Merge Two Sorted lists

Tags: linked-list, mergesort, dummy-variable

I'm trying to understand the dummy node outputNode and tail node here.

I just have one more question, after declaring the outputNode and tail, there is no interaction between them during the whole process, then how does the final result appear in outputNode.next?

Thanks a million

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
        ListNode outputNode = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode tail= outputNode;
        while(list1 != null && list2 != null){
            if(list1.val < list2.val){
                tail.next = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
            }else{
                tail.next = list2;
                list2 = list2.next;
            }
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        if(list1 == null&& list2 != null){
            tail.next = list2;
            list2 = list2.next;
             
        }
        if(list1 != null&& list2 == null){
            tail.next = list1;
            list1 = list1.next;
           
        }
        return outputNode.next;
                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to visualise the process. Let's say we merge two lists with values 1, 4 and 2, 3 respectively:

Once the first two statements before the loop are executed, we have `tail` and `outputNode` referencing the same "dummy" node:

```
tail
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next:null │
└───────────┘

list1
  ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

In the first iteration of the loop, the first `if` condition is true, and so `tail.next = list1`
gets executed. This leads to the following:

```
tail
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
list1    │ 
  ↓      ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

Note how it doesn't matter whether you look at it via `outputNode` or via `tail`, either way you get to the node that now has a `next` member that points to the first node of `list1`.

The next statement assigns a different node reference to `list1` with `list1 = list1.next`:

```
tail
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
         │      list1
         ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

The last statement in the first iteration of the loop, moves the tail reference, with `tail = tail.next`:

```
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
tail     │      list1
  ↓      ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘

┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

In the second iteration of the loop, we get into the `else` block, and there we set `tail.next = list2`:

```
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
tail     │      list1
  ↓      ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑
list2
```

Then `list1 = list1.next` will lead to:

```
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
tail     │      list1
  ↓      ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
                  ↑
                 list2
```

And again, the final statement of this second iteration, will move `tail`:

```
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
         │      list1
         ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next:null │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
  ↑               ↑
tail            list2
```

And then the third iteration will deliver this state:

```
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
         │      list1
         ▼        ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
                  ↑        
                tail       list2 == null
```

The part after the loop, will do `tail.next = list1` in the last `if` block. The assignment to `list2` really is not needed anymore.
The final state is:

```
outputNode
  ↓
┌───────────┐
│ data: 0   │
│ next: ─┐  │
└────────│──┘
         │
         │                 list1 == null
         ▼
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 4   │
│ next: ─┐  │   │ next:null │
└────────│──┘   └───────────┘
         ▼                ▲
┌───────────┐   ┌─────────│─┐
│ data: 2   │   │ data: 3 │ │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──┘ │
└───────────┘   └───────────┘
                  ↑        
                tail       list2 == null
```

The return value is `outputNode.next`, which indeed is the reference to the first node of the merged list.

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: May I ask a further question on this, the ` ListNode outputNode = new ListNode(0); `  is a creation of new object, while ` ListNode tail= outputNode; ` is a declaration of a variable as Node type. What's the difference between these two kinds of nodes?

Comment: Both are node references. The first statement creates a node and its reference is assigned. The second gets the same reference.

Comment: I apologize for not marking the answer as accepted earlier. Your response did indeed answer my question and provided a thorough explanation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The last bit of code to handle the rest of the remaining sorted list can be simplified, since there's no need to update tail or list1 or list2 at that point.

```
        if(list1 == null)
            tail.next = list2;
        else
            tail.next = list1;
```