# Unable To Understand Line of Codes For Linked List

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to understand `Linked List` and got a code sample that has two lists. The code sample is basic but am stuck in few sections to understand. It merges two lists and do a sort. Here's the code snippet that I am struggling with - [Linked List](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q5UTZa)

```
head = list1;

while ((list1.next != null) && (list2 != null)) 
{
  ListNode n = list1.next;
  ListNode t = list2.next;
  
  list1.next = list2;
  list2.next = n;
  
  list1 = list1.next;
  list2 = t;
}
```

I can understand and pretty sure that the above code snippet merges two lists into one keeping the list1 into head. Finally it does the sorting that I am clear enough. But the thing is how it does the merging  in the above code, am unable to understand. I would appreciate if anyone can give a brief example like how the code works. In the same time, there are some sample inputs. I am willing to know if it's true, it maintains **FIFO** (First-in-first-out) in this particular code sample.

**N.B**: I tried to do debugging, though nothing much I could understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging two linked lists - how does the dummy node get updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69922937/merging-two-linked-lists-how-does-the-dummy-node-get-updated)

Comment: This code inserts all the nodes of the second list right between the first two nodes of the first list. From the link I see that this is part of a method called `MergeSortedList` which suggests that the input lists are sorted. This means this code is rubbish. Don't look further into it. There are more efficient ways to merge two sorted lists.

Comment: Can you provide a better sample to study @trincot? Thanks for your suggestion, I am expecting some better ways.

Comment: The correct algorithm has been discussed in many Q&A and variations on this site. For some I have provided my answer, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72937725/5459839), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72976352/5459839), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69922937/5459839)...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an implementation of Merge Sort. That part only merge two lists into one. In the given link there, in the code, a Bubble Sort pass just after. So this merges two lists into one and applies a Bubble Sort, that is a **Bubble Sort**.

How this loop works? Suppose you have:

- list1: a1 -> a2 -> a3...
- list2: b1 -> b2 -> b3...

First `head = list1` makes head pointing to a1 ->....

The while condition is true, so:

- `ListNode n = list1.next;`, makes n pointing to a2 ->...
- `ListNode t = list2.next;`makes t pointing to b2 ->...
- `list1.next = list2;` makes lists1: a1 -> b1 -> ...
- `list2.next = n;` makes list2: b1 -> a2 -> ...
- `list1 = list1.next;` makes list1: b1 -> b2 ->...
- `list2 = t;` makes list2: b2 -> b3 ->...

For one pass in the loop you will end with head now pointing to a1 -> b1 -> a2 -> a3...

At the end of this loop you will have head pointing to a1 -> b1 -> b2 ->... -> a2 -> a3 ->...

That inserts the elements of list2 in between the two first elements of list1.

That is certainly not Merge Sort, has the merging in Merge Sort preserve the order of merged elements. Have a look at the merging suggested in the comment by @Renat.

Comment: I think the method is just badly named. I don't think the author tried to implement a sorting algorithm. He just wanted to "merge" and preserve order of both inputs not additional sort them.

Comment: I can understand that @Jean-Baptiste Yunès. Can you provide an example with the sample inputs that I ptovided like how they work in that particular code snippet?

Comment: I told you, at the beginning if you have 1 2 3 and 6 7 8 you will get 1 6 7 8 2 3. And you can just print the lists just after the while and see what happens...